# Заказ клиента

Tags: 1с

1С:Предприятие 8.2 (8.2.17.153)

Создаю документ "заказ клиента":

```
НовыйДок = Документы.ЗаказКлиента.СоздатьДокумент();
```

заполняю поля `"Дата"`, `"Контрагент"`, ...

Добавляю товары. Заполняю у них поля `Номенклатура`, `Количество`, `КоличествоУпаковок`, `Цена`, `Сумма`, `СтавкаНДС`, `Склад`.

Записываю документ:

```
НовыйДок.Записать(РежимЗаписиДокумента.Проведение);
```

1с выдает ошибку:

> {ОбщийМодуль.ДополнительныйМодуль.Модуль(247)}:
> Ошибка при вызове метода контекста
> (Записать): Запись не верна! Период не
> может быть пустым! (Регистр
> накопления: Движение товаров; Номер
> строки: 1)

Пытался добавить этот `период` и к самому документу и к товарам, но выдает ошибку: "Поле объекта не обнаружено".

Что за сие `"Период"` и куда его прикрутить?

Comment: Надо посмотреть процедуры ПриСозданииНаСервере, ПриОткрытии и другие обработчики - при добавлении строки в табличную часть, изменении номенклатуры. Там идут вызовы процедур из общих модулей, которые заполняют кучу реквизитов, необходимых, чтоб документ был корректным. Это удача, что ошибка обнаружилась при проведении, возможна ситуация когда все проведется и проведется неверно, потом будет куча головной боли по корректировке сбойных документов.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov спасибо, учту.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тебе надо посмотреть, как проводится объект в модуле объекта. Может в обработчике проводки нет записи периода в соответствующее поле регистра.

Comment: @teanЫЧ точно! Починил.

Answer (score 1):

Все просто. Документ делает движения по каким то регистрам, так вот при движении по регистру не задан период. Ищите в модуле документа - обработка проведения.